# Hyperkähler quotient of left $\operatorname{SU}(2)$-action on $(\mathbb{C}^2)^m \cong \mathbb{H}^m$

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, holomorphic-symplectic, hyperkaehler

The natural $\operatorname{SU}(2)$-action on quaternions $\mathbb{H}\cong\mathbb{C}^2$ is hyperkähler. Extending it naturally to $\mathbb{H}^m$, one can make a hyperkähler quotient (where $\mu=(\mu_I,\mu_J,\mu_K)$ is the hyperkähler moment map):
$$M_{m}= \mu^{-1}(c)/\operatorname{SU}(2)$$ of dimension 4(m-3). In particular,
$M_4$ is a 4-dimensional hyperkähler manifold (for generic $c$ that makes it smooth)

Does anyone know which manifold this is? Or $M_m$ in general?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the hyperkaehler moment map construction, but I do know that the quotient of $({\mathbb C}^2)^m=({\mathbb C}^m)^2$ by ${\rm SL}_2$ is isomorphic to the space of all skew-symmetric $m\times m$ complex matrices of rank $\leq 2$. To see this, write such matrices as $u\wedge v$ and note that for $u,v$ linearly independent, $(au+bv)\wedge (cu+dv)=u\wedge v$ if and only if $ad-bc=1$. It looks like your $M_m$ is somehow related. (Are you sure about the dimension...?)